# Select nth child in xQuery / select next element

Tags: select, xquery

I am having trouble finding good xQuery tutorials, basically what I am trying to do is retreive the text  `etc...` from this html node

```
<div class="venue">
    <div class="vitem">
        <p style="padding: 6px 0pt 0pt;" class="label">ADDRESS:</p>
        <p class="item-big">blabla</p>
    </div><br class="clear">
    <div class="vitem">
        <p style="padding: 6px 0pt 0pt;" class="label">PHONE:</p>
        <p class="item-big">123</p>
    </div><br class="clear">
    <div class="vitem">
        <p style="padding: 6px 0pt 0pt;" class="label">WEB:</p>
        <p class="item-big">etc...</p>
    </div><br class="clear">
</div>
```

I'd like to know how can I get the data out of the 2nd p in the *third* `div[@class="vitem"]`
Or the p *directly following* the `p[@class="label"]` that *contains* the text `WEB:`

**Edit:** Answeres already helped a great bit, however my second question is if the layout changes to something like this

```
<div class="venue">
    <div class="vitem">
        <p style="padding: 6px 0pt 0pt;" class="label">ADDRESS:</p>
        <p class="item-big">blabla</p>
    </div><br class="clear">
    <div class="vitem">
        <p style="padding: 6px 0pt 0pt;" class="label">WEB:</p>
        <p class="item-big">etc...</p>
    </div><br class="clear">
</div>
```

How do i get the `etc...`, knowing only that it follows a p with the class label containing the text `WEB:`?  it's no longer in div[3]/p[2]

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two XPath expressions that select exactly the wanted nodes. Also, I explain in simple English what each of these expression means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to know how can I get the
>   data out of the 2nd p in the third
>   div[@class="vitem"]

**Use**:

```
/*/div[@class='vitem'][3]/p[2]/text()
```

This means: get all the text node children of the second `p` child of the third of all `div` elements that have an attribute `class` with value `"vitem"` and that are children of the top element.

> Or the p directly following the
>   p[@class="label"] with the data WEB:

**Use**:

```
/*/div[@class='vitem'][3]/p[@class='label']
                             /following-sibling::p[1]/text()
```

This means: get all the text node children of the first following-sibling `p` of any `p` element with `class` attribute with value `"label"`, that is a child of the third of all `div` elements that have an attribute `class` with value `"vitem"` and that are children of the top element.

**UPDATE**: The OP has added a second question: he wants just to select the `p` that has as a string value the text "etc..."

**Use**:

```
/*/div/p[.='etc...']
```

Comment: Cool, the examples are both good, but what i meant with `directly following the p[@class="label"] that contains the text WEB:`  was if I don't know that the text `WEB:` is located in `div[@class='vitem'][3]`, I only know there should be a item somewhere containing the text WEB:

Comment: @Moak: Then update your question. In XPath there is a strict terminology, so that people can understand each other.

Comment: I did update my question, I'm not sure about what terminology I was using wrongly, apologies in any case. I need to  select `/following-sibling::p[1]/text()` from the div that contains the text() WEB: see my update. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again dimitre, again my expresion was not quite clear, but your update did bring me to the solution I was looking for:
`/*/p[.="WEB:"]/following-sibling::p[1]/text()` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know how can I get the
>   data out of the 2nd p in the *third*
>   `div[@class="vitem"]` Or the p *directly following* the `p[@class="label"]`

The semantically equal XPath/XQuery expressions are:

```
/div
   /div[@class='vitem'][3]
      /p[2]
```

Or

```
/div
   /div[@class='vitem'][3]
      /p[@class='label']
         /following-sibling::p[1]
```