# Iterate over XML tags with same name

Tags: scala, akka

I have this XML text:

```
<apps>
  <app><id>"abcde"</id></app>
  <app><id>"xyz"</id></app>
  <app><id>"bcn"</id></app>
</apps>
```

I'm using the library `scala.xml` to handle it.

I would like to iterate over the `app` tags in a for loop like this:

```
(xmlText \\ "apps" \\ "app").foreach(app => {
   //do something
}
```

However, in this case I can only get the first `app` tag.

How can I specify that I want the second one, third one, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me:

```
import scala.xml.Elem
import scala.xml.XML

object TagIter {
  val xmlText = <apps>
                  <app><id>"abcde"</id></app>
                  <app><id>"xyz"</id></app>
                  <app><id>"bcn"</id></app>
                </apps>
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    (xmlText \\ "apps" \\ "app").foreach { app =>
      //do something
      println(app.text)
    }
  }
}

"abcde"
"xyz"
"bcn"
```

Your code certainly iterates over all the nodes. If you want to act only on the N-th node, you can add a variable that keeps track of how many you have seen so far.

There's this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468461/select-nth-child-in-xquery-select-next-element

If you apply an index to the expression, you select one node:

```
(xmlText \\ "apps" \\ "app")(1)
"xyz"
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a completely different issue in my code actually.